# loop for path name with space fails

Tags: batch, batch-file

I have problem with looping through file which path name contains space

```
SET MPATH=\\server\path\some folder with space\Sample.txt
for /f %%a in ("%MPATH%") do (set file=%%~fa)
for /f "skip=1 tokens=2,160 delims=^|" %%a in (%file%) do (
echo something^|%%a^|something^|%%b^|>>"C:\Directory\temp.txt"
)
```

Output:

```
The system cannot find the file \\server\path\some.
```

I have looked through multiple threads suggesting:

1. .. in ("\server\path\some folder with space\Sample.txt") do (set
   file=%%~fa)
2. .. in ('dir /b /s \server\path\some folder with space\Sample.txt')
3. .. in ('type \server\path\some folder with space\Sample.txt')

but none seems to do the trick, with the same result:

```
The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to do. Are you trying to read the **contents** of `\\server\path\some folder with space\Sample.txt`? Can you [edit] your question to include the contents of this file? What exactly do you want to do with each line in the file when you have it?

Comment: `for /f "usebackq skip=1 tokens=2,160 delims=^|" %%a in ("%file%") do` or equivalent `for /f "skip=1 tokens=2,160 delims=^|" %%a in ('type "%file%"') do`